# How do I modify this code to create a loop inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I found this script from a website. The loop ends when it has followed 40 Instagram accounts at a 2-second interval. How do I modify the script so it waits for 10 minutes before repeating the same loop for 3 times? Basically, it goes:

1. Follow an account and wait for 2 seconds X40
2. Wait for 10 minutes
3. Follow an account and wait for 2 seconds X40
4. Wait for 10 minutes
5. Follow an account and wait for two seconds X40
6. Wait for 10 minutes
7. ---LOOP ENDS---

```
 var TagFollow = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
 var SearchFollow = "Follow";
 var foundFollow;

 function clickfollow(){
 for (var i = 0; i < TagFollow.length; i++) {
     if (TagFollow[i].textContent == SearchFollow) {
     foundFollow = TagFollow[i];
     foundFollow.click(); 
     break;
      }
 }
 }
var i = 1;
function myLoop() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
        clickfollow();
        //document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[3].scrollIntoView(false
         i++;
         if (i < 41) {
            myLoop();
          }
     }, 2000)
}
 myLoop();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need nested loops. You can "linearize" them in single loop (I do not recall the correct therm now). So basically you want loop of `3 * 40 = 120` and after each 40 you need to use increased delay of `10 * 60 * 1000 = 600000`. You help yourself by using modulo function `i%40`. Because you start with 1, the each 40th iteration is when remainder of `i` divided with 40 is zero.

So basically change `if (i < 41)` to `if (i < 121)` and `}, 2000)` to `}, i%40 === 0 ? 600000 : 2000)`

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question. When I move to other tabs while executing the script, why doesn't it follow 40 accounts before the 10 minute delay? I mean, it follows like only 14 or 15 accounts and then it stops.